# Permissions to add SPN to computer account

Tags: active-directory, rhel

I am trying to add some RHEL6 boxes to an S2008R2 domain. Part of the [process](https://fedorahosted.org/sssd/wiki/Configuring%20sssd%20to%20authenticate%20with%20a%20Windows%202008%20Domain%20Server#CreatingServiceKeytabonAD) is to create a computer account in AD, then add an SPN to it.

Pretty much all guides say that you need Admin privileges on AD, but that is not available to me. I want to give the Linux Admins the minimum rights possible on AD. Can any one tell me what rights they need on the target OU to do this?

Adding Computer objects is obvious, but then they cannot add the SPN.

If I take step back and try it from the Linux side (using *net ads join creatupn="host\jhgfjg"*) then it adds the object, but once again does not add the SPN.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually for serverfault.com but I will answer it anyway.

Install Samba on your machine, set it up and do as root

```
net ads join -U<adminaccount>@<realm>
net ads keytab create
net ads keytab add <SPN>
```

You're done.

Comment: no, that does not answer my question (which I have posted to Server fault realising my mistake). Your response assumes admin privileges, which in this case is not an option. Giving Linux admins the exact rights they need is however.